# Цикл +1 по зданному времени

Tags: javascript, php, циклы

Подскажите, как написать цикл на PHP или JS, где каждый день в 9 утра (время берем GMT+5) переменная принимает значение  = 1? Затем, каждые последующие 2 часа +1. Завершаем цикл в 19 вечера. А с 00 до 9 утра блок с выводом переменной на сайт, должен быть скрыт (style="display:none").

Comment: А зачем цикл (с каким-то таймером вероятно), если расписание смены значения жёстко фиксированное? Не проще на основании текущего времени отображать нужное значение?

Comment: Писать лучше на JS или PHP?

Comment: Если просто показать картинку посетителю -- на js, если это значение как-то ещё используется -- можно и на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $options = [9 => 1, 10 => 2, 11 => 2, ...., 19 => ..];
 $h = date("G");
 $value = $options[$h] ?? 0;
 if ($value) {
    echo "<div>{$value}</div>";
 }
```

если на сервере какой-то иной часовой пояс, то учтите это самостоятельно.

Comment: 3-ю строку можете прокомментировать? $value = $options[$h] ?? 0;

Comment: возвращает ноль при отсутствие ключа в массиве